# transfer files from icloud and one drive to desktop running ubuntu

Tags: files, downloads, transfer

I cannot download file folders from iCloud drive and OneDrive to my computer. I can on Google Drive. Photos are fine and individual files but not file folders.

[image]

Is there a way without individually downloading each and every file?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

Like most things on Linux thesedays, there's a snap for that! I've listed native apps avaliable which will let you bulk download all your files, and even sync them with the cloud! This means that you can download your files, but not through the Web Interface.

**iCloud**

The `iCloud` snap will automatically allow you to access the files stored within iCloud drive, as well as iCloud Reminders, Calendar, and notes.

It's really easy to install, just follow the instructions here, and you should be able to access your iCloud files from your Ubuntu device (they even sync for you!):
https://snapcraft.io/install/icloud-for-linux/ubuntu

**OneDrive**

There's also a OneDrive client for Ubuntu which supports OneDrive, though you'll have to install it in two-steps.

1. Follow the instructions here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/ubuntu-package-install.md
   (that's the non-GUI base)
2. Install the GUI by downloading the latest AppImage from here: https://github.com/bpozdena/OneDriveGUI/releases
   (on Jammy Jellyfish+, you'll have to run this command before  running the AppImage: `sudo apt install libfuse2`.

(If you don't know how to install AppImages, there are many helpful tutorials out on the Web!)

Thanks for your time in reading through this answer.

Comment: The iCloud snap app seems to be a simple wrapper for the web browser interface (icloud.com), as mentioned in the Snap store reviews. It won't sync with your file system. See also the discussion at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275937/is-it-possible-to-run-icloud-drive-on-ubuntu.